# regex with condition to replace "-" or "_" before the file extension with a dot

Tags: php, regex

examples:

```
this-is_a-random-filenam-jpg
this-is_a-random-filenam-png
this-is_a-random-filenam-gif
this-is_a-random-filenam-pdf
```

needed result:

```
this-is_a-random-filenam.jpg
this-is_a-random-filenam.png
this-is_a-random-filenam.gif
this-is_a-random-filenam.pdf
```

I came up with

```
\-(?=[^-]*$)
```

it just marks the last occurrence, doesn't check the condition that there is an actual valid file extension after it (jpeg,jpg,pdf,gif in my case) and doesn't work with "_".

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~-(jpg|png|gif|pdf)$~', '.$1', $s)`

Comment: and for the _ case?

Comment: Use `preg_replace('~[-_](jpe?g|png|gif|pdf)$~', '.$1', $s)`, or make it also case insensitive - `preg_replace('~[-_](jpe?g|png|gif|pdf)$~i', '.$1', $s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Expression

To perform this change by taking care of file extension, you can use this regex:

```
(-|_)(?=(?:jpe?g|png|gif|pdf)$)
```

And replace the matches with a `.`.

> You will have to list all file extensions you want in this pattern.

[See the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZQSFx/1)

#### PHP example

```
$re = '/(-|_)(?=(?:jpe?g|png|gif|pdf)$)/';
$str = 'this-is_a-random-filenam-jpg
this-is_a-random-filenam-png
this-is_a-random-filenam-gif
this-is_a-random-filenam-pdf';
$subst = '.';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: Consider changing `jpg` tp `jpe?g` to cover OP request.

Comment: @Ibrahim Thx for noticing, I've updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

use following flags at the end of your regular expression

`/(-|_)(?=jpg|png|gif|pdf)/gm`